# Removing a file from C++ code using QFile::remove() is leaving .nfsxxxxx file?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using following code to remove a file.

```
QFile::remove( filePath );
```

But it is still leaving some .nfxxxxxx files at the directory. 
What could be the possible reason?

Comment: Were the .nfxxxxxx files in the directory to begin with?

Comment: No.. each time my process deletes the file, a copy of it with .nfxxxxxx gets created.

Answer (score 0):

The file you're removing is on an NFS mount.  NFS is creating these files, and it will delete them on its own.  This has nothing to do with Qt.